# SoundPool Null Pointer

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, soundpool

My app is a children's app with 4 games (separate activies) that all require the same sounds. There are something like 150 1-2 second sounds that I load into a SoundPool file in a class separate from these activities (Config.java) when the app is first opened. When resuming the app from within any 1 of the 4 games I check if the SoundPool is still loaded with:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (Config.spool != null) {}
    else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);}
}
```

where MainActivity (in onCreate) calls for Config.java to recreate the SoundPool, provides a loading/logo screen for 3 seconds and then takes user back to the GameSelector activity where they can choose a game. Through testing I didn't run into any null pointer exceptions. I published this app 3 weeks ago and yesterday I got the first report of a null pointer when requesting to play a sound in the onCreate of one of the games (this is line 243):

```
if (voice == 2) {Sound(Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice2[currentIndex]);}
```

Is it possible this is because the SoundPool isn't fully loaded? I can't duplicate the problem. Stack trace from force close report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123/com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123.Game2Show}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123.Game2Show.setImages(Game2Show.java:243)
at com.zenlifegames.teachtryabc123.Game2Show.onCreate(Game2Show.java:57)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
... 11 more
```

I'm ready to post code as requested, just not sure what will help and what will clutter the question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, thanks! I have line 243 in my question but didn't indicate that is what it is until I thought to edit a minute ago.

Comment: So, I know it's the sound resource I'm pointing to which is null, I just don't know why it's null.

Comment: There are several things on that line that could be null. Try running through it with a debugger to see *which* it is. If you can, sometimes these things aren't very reproducible.

Comment: I am sure voice and currentIndex are not null as they are used earlier in the method without issue. The null is the sound resource at Config.alphabetSoundsArray_voice2

Comment: To clarify, debugging doesn't help me because I can't duplicate the null pointer exception. It's a report I got from a google play user.